# Improper rendering of Vietnamese font in a webpage

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have been facing this issue wherein the font of some language for suppose Vietnamese in this case shows some parts of the text in a different form or in a bold version of that form

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNxz7.jpg)

On researching a bit I have found out that this issue is centric to chrome(as far as I know) and if a particular language is not specified as a document's language then some other language's fonts are borrowed in between. Well I am not totally sure about this research and it looks vague to me.

I would really want the entire font to be formatted properly instead of some being bold and some being normal

Comment: Can you verify that you have employed the same character encoding throughout your code? Have you verified that the font file includes the Vietnamese characters? Show your code, if possible.

Comment: In your font set, which font file types do you have? Like what extensions?

Comment: @Parapluie yes there is same character encoding throughout the code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are currently using any font family (Like Lato), and it doesn't have support for the Vietnamese language.
https://fonts.google.com/?subset=vietnamese
https://generatepress.com/forums/topic/bold-characters-in-vietnamese/